# Difference between referencing and asking for variable address

Tags: c++, reference, memory-address

In the frame of an overloading operator exercise, I found various coding methods for referencing "Type& variable" and I variable addressing "Type &variable"

the prototype under Duree.h is the following (constant reference):

```
Duree& operator+=(Duree const& duree)
```

I understand from this code that both parameter and instance are subject to reference (meaning they (the argument and instance) will be directly modified when the method is executed -except if const is integrated for the parameter-).

the method downstream is the following under Duree.cpp:

```
Duree& Duree::operator+=(const Duree &duree2)
{
XXX
}
```

I understand that the instance is subject to reference, but the parameter here seems to be the adress of duree2. The code seems to work well. Does this have the same meaning as:

```
Duree& Duree::operator+=(const Duree& duree2)
    {
    XXX
    }
```

Or is there a fundamental difference in the compilation between stiking the "&" to the type or to the variable?

Thanks

Comment: `Does this have the same meaning as...` yes.

Comment: Does it mean that I could write &Duree Duree::operator+=(const& Duree duree2) ?

Comment: It's the same as `char* fred;` and `char *fred;` when declaring a variable. No (essential) difference, just a matter of preference

Comment: Whitespace between tokens doesn't matter in nearly every case. You can't swap two tokens in most cases, so no, `const& Duree duree2` is not valid. http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html

Comment: Vico, no, not like that, it's only the amount of spaces that does not matter. A good exercise is to read them right-to-left: `const Duree& duree2` - "duree2 is a reference to a Duree constant object"

Comment: Thanks I did not know that referencing and addressing were the same function (Is logical though)

Comment: No, `&Duree Duree::operator...` would not be valid. As other comments say, you can (mostly) move/ignore whitespace between `type & varname` but you cannot swap `type&` for `&type`.

Answer (score 2):

The space is just a space, nothing more than a token separator. (You can even omit both spaces, `T&t` is valid.)

Attaching to the type or the variable is a convention originally came from C:

```
int* x;
```

This makes the type looks like `int*`.

However, this won't work:

```
int* x, y;
```

In this case, `y` is treated as normal `int`.

Thus, some people started to prefer this style:

```
int *x, *y;
```

This declares two pointers.

The semantic in C++ references is basically same, and they're just a formatting convention.